# Why can't I sneak by pressing shift?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I believe I changed the controls in Minecraft because I was messing around in the settings and now my character is not sneaking when I press shift. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Dumb question, but are you low on food?

Answer (score 1):

This probably caused by the key bindings being changed.

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to pause the game.

Go to "Options"… → "Controls…" → "Key Binds…".

You can either press "Reset Keys" on the bottom part of the screen, or press the button beside the "Sneak" and press "Left Shift" to set it to "Left Shift".

If the key is highlighted red, it means that you have used the same key in another control. For example, if Jump is set to Space, and  Sprint is set to Space, you have to change one of the keys to another key.

Comment: @MrParrot no, Control is the default key for sprinting, and Shift is default for sneaking. Maybe *you* changed your controls and now think they are default.

Comment: @Esther That's exactly what I was trying to say. Ironically, I ended up saying the exact opposite (I must've typed it quickly), and since the answer was edited (a day later, probably because of my comment) it made it look like I was the one making the mistake. At the time the answer incorrectly stated that the default key for sprinting is left shift.